# Point farthest from n other points in a cube in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy, discrete-mathematics

I want to find the point[s] which are the farthest away from n other points within a three dimensional cube. I tried playing around scipy.spatial.Voronoi, but I couldn't figure it out (The answers I got was outside the cube). I'm not very good at this type of maths, and I would appreciate if you could refer me to a library which does most of the maths or some code that I can just copy.

Edit: I see how asking for a library was off-topic, and of course all helpful answers would be highly appreciated! And thanks to Mathieu's answer I think I have a better understanding of my problem.

What I tried was:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import Voronoi

def get_points(points)
    np_points = np.array(points)
    vor = Voronoi(np_points)
    fartest_point = None
    fartest_point_length = np.inf
    for vertex in vor.vertices:
        min_length = np.inf
        for p in points:
            length = norm(p-vertex)
            if length < min_length:
                min_length = length
        if min_length < fartest_point_length:
            fartest_point = vertex
            fartest_point_length = min_length
    return fartest_point

points = [[2, 3, 5], [8, 2, 6], [10, 3, 5], [2, 3, 2], ...]
point = get_points(points)
```

The problem is that I get points outside of the cube. I think the problem is that I don't get the points where the region touch the edge of the cube.

Comment: You might need to define "farthest away from n other points". Isn't it going to be one of the vertices? Btw I'm not a downvoter ;)

Comment: In euclidean distance. Could you explain what you mean by "Isn't it going to be one of the vertices"?

Comment: Don't you only have to check eight different points of the cube?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this site is to help programmers, not to locate bits of code that you can "just copy" without understanding.

Comment: No because it could be any point within the cube. For example if the n points were near a corner, the points farthest away from all of them would be in the middle. I think the problem I have is the [Largest empty sphere problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Largest_empty_sphere)

Comment: You're correct that this is the largest empty sphere problem. You should [edit] this *question* adding your newly-found knowledge so that it doesn't get closed. Include everything that you've got, including the code that you've written for the Voronoi. Also, did you read [the paper](https://www.cs.swarthmore.edu/~adanner/cs97/s08/papers/schuster.pdf)

Comment: Well closed already. Scipy it should have been.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have some code to provide you but I can share my understanding of your problem :

> find the point[s] farthest away from n other points within a three
> dimensional cube

I also believe Voronoi is a good way to tackle your issue but it is not as straightforward as looking at the vertices of the Voronoi Diagram.

First **as you can see on the example from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram#Illustration) even though all the points are within a square, some vertices from the Voronoi diagram will be outside the square** (the purple region on the top right corner will have a vertex outside for instance), so it's normal you got some vertices outside the cube.

In your problem you have 2 kind of vertices that are candidates for being farthest away :

1. Voronoi vertices being inside the cube
2. Vertices from intersection between regions going outside the
   boundaries of the cube and the cube : *on the wikipedia example
   that would be all the points that separate regions and touch the
   boundaries*

You would then need to compute the distance of these candidates from the closest points and then deduce the farthest point[s].

Good luck solving your problem, hope that helps

*NB: The largest empty sphere problem is different as if you take a square and two points, one vertex and the center of the square, you want to return the opposite vertex*